# Rspec, calling methods on factory object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a factory that creates a "Character" object, but before I can this object, I must call a method called "init" that instantiates a lot of important attributes and associations. How would I call this method before I start testing the character object?

Because it interacts with a DB, I don't think it would be a good idea to call it at each "it" block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [at the the doc here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks).

There are useful callbacks you can add in your factories:

> - after(:build) - called after a factory is built (via FactoryGirl.build, FactoryGirl.create)
> - before(:create) - called before a factory is saved (via FactoryGirl.create)
> - after(:create) - called after a factory is saved (via FactoryGirl.create)
> - after(:stub) - called after a factory is stubbed (via FactoryGirl.build_stubbed)